# How to run android pdf viewer source code in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-source

I have downloaded android pdf viewer(apv) from http://code.google.com/p/apv/ . Now i want to import this source code in eclipse and i want to run it from eclipse.Please tell me step by step procedure for it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the source code from google website and import your source code into your eclipse path.After that u have to add libs floder.or getting any project of lib folder and paste it to your project folder.

then click window-preferences-java build path-Enable the button and change into JDK.1.5

U will get a pdf viewer in your emulator..

Comment: Please add library otherwise u never get output